# Подмена данных, загружаемых из файла подкачки в Linux

Tags: linux, файлы, swap, ядро

Исходя из прочтения Таненбаума «Операционные системы...» был сделан следующий вывод: *чтобы страницы в оперативной памяти, содержащие код и константные значения не хранились в файле подкачки (точнее не дублировались на диске) их считывают из исходного файла запущенной программы, хранящейся на диске*.

### Вопрос в следующем

1. Ядро из-за нехватки памяти, выгружает процесс в своп. Что произойдет если мы удалили исходный файл, создали новый с таким же именем (для усложнения получилось так что *inode* файла получился тот же, что и у предыдущего; если такое возможно, просьба знающих уточнить). Ведь ядро при чтении файла загрузит уже новые данные? Или нет? Конечно есть *dentry* указывающая на файл, и пока есть ссылки на него она существует (хотя здесь могу ошибаться, ядро может её почистить вроде, из-за нехватки памяти).
2. Если такое происходит, может ли ядро полностью перенести данные из удаленного файла в своп и создать новый файл?

### Появились соображения

Возможно, ядро видя, что страница памяти больше не соотвествует странице на диске (по идее должна её заменить, сбросить из кеша, но вряд ли), отвязывает её от диска и навсегда переносит в ОЗУ(ну или своп).

Скорее всего туже ноду невозможно будет назначить, пока на старую есть ссылки из dentry. Наверное, стоит копать в сторону обновления программ и библиотек, как они выполняются. Перезапускаются или переподключают свои библиотеки.

Comment: при создании нового (подмене) файла что-то должно произойти со страницами памяти - про грязные страницы в книге тоже написано. Думаю  что таким образом не удастся обмануть ядро. (полезность моего коммента зацкаливает %:)). А не хотите ли проверить на практике  "подмену"? Напишите пару строк кода и узнаете.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, про грязные(изменена в кеше, но не на диске) страницы и сказано - ядро грязные страницы сбрасывает на диск(нет памяти, время подошло...), но данные изменились на диске, а не в озу. Думаю пару строк не выйдет, я не знаю как заставить ядро выгрузить в своп весь процесс. Даже не знаю как это проверить. Думаю разработчики однозначно учли в системе ответ на мой вопрос, но я мне бы хотелось узнать, как вс-таки это реализовано. Попробую порыть в сети как это реализуется, но для меня будет сложно, хотя задача интересная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> для усложнения получилось так что inode файла получился тот же, что и у предыдущего

это возможно разве что только в результате сбоя в коде, работающем с файловой системой.

ведь процесс, запущенный из файла с таким-то [*inode*-ом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), пока выполняется, использует этот самый *inode*.

можете самостоятельно убедиться в этом с помощью, например, программы `lsof`. к примеру, текущий процесс оболочки использует (в моём случае) файл `/bin/bash`:

```
$ lsof -p $$ | grep 'COMMAND\|/bin/bash'
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
bash    3236 user  txt    REG  254,0  1029624 130322 /bin/bash
```

а точнее, файл с *inode*-ом 130322:

```
$ ls -i /bin/bash
130322 /bin/bash
```

и даже если я удалю в каталоге `/bin` «каталожную запись» про файл `bash`, *inode* никуда не денется:

> [если какие-либо процессы ещё не закрыли файл, то они могут удерживать доступ к нему, а файл будет окончательно удален только после того, как будет закрыто последнее обращение к нему](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode#.D0.97.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5)

Comment: Это то, что мне и было интересно. Процесс держит ссылку на ноду, поэтому нода с тем же номером создаться не может. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

так ты файл удалишь и создашь, но ведь не будет файл после запуска повторно открываться - оно может быть уже заммапено в адресное пространство процесса. и созданный тобой файл не обязательно же запишется в те сектора диска, в которых был исходный файл.

Comment: Я рассматриваю самую крайнюю ситуацию - всё плохо, сектора совпали, нода та же. То есть в конечном итоге файл будет новый, а старый файл отмапленный на память, будет находиться вечно в памяти (в свопе) пока приложение работает, и когда страницы потребуются он будет читать их уже не с фс, а со свопа? Я правильно рассуждаю. Если до, то как это хотя бы реализуется в кратце, как ядро понимает, что не надо лезть в файл на диске?