# Как в Linux остановить и поместить весь процесс в своп, а после возобновить

Tags: linux, swap, ядро

Задача:
приостанавливаем процесс, помещаем его в swap(то есть полностью убираем из оперативной памяти. Обязательно полностью!). Потом по требованию возобновляем процесс(то есть он полностью грузится из файла подкачки). Как это реализовать.
Подспорье для вопроса [Подмена данных, загружаемых из файла подкачки в Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601782/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-linux)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134771/how-to-hibernate-a-process-in-linux-by-storing-its-memory-to-disk-and-restorin# Помимо этого есть механизм checkpoint-restore, из CRIU, но там поддержка ядра.

Answer (score 1):

вроде бы невозможно такое. в linux можно только swappiness настраивать и все.
пошли процессу SIGSTOP и жди когда выгрузится в swap.

Comment: наверное придется копаться в ядре, писать свой модуль и собирать ядро потом. но так понимаю задача вообще не из лёгких

Comment: как узнать сколько страниц у процесса в свопе, в памяти(какие именно страницы там)?  хотя инфа какие именно мало что даст, но всё же есть какая то утилита, имеющая функционал чтения памяти(не виртуальной, физической)?

Comment: посмотри /proc/$pid/maps - там написано что по какому адресу расположено. а зачем тебе физические адреса то вообще?

Comment: они не нужны. сначала была идея, что зная физический адрес можно было узнать - страница в свопе или всё же в памяти, но неправильный ход мысли.